# Cannot enter input in multiple lines via command line for feeding Java code

Tags: java

I want to enter something like this on the command line as an input and process it in the Java code

```
21 4 -2 31 23 0 10 28 -6 19
1
5
20
8
0
```

But as soon as I push <kbd>Enter</kbd> the program starts executing and I cannot enter the next line.

How can I do it?

Comment: what is sth? What is the "21  4 -2 31..."?

Comment: Try pasting your input all at once

Comment: I'm guessing that "sth" is shorthand for "something". I think he's going to want to read input from the console once the program starts, rather than relying only on the command line arguments to the executable.

Comment: this is an array and the single numbers in other lines means for example the first or fifth or ... smallest element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enter multiple inputs, use any input API, like *java.util.scanner*, inside the *for* loop where the *for* loop will iterate for numbers you want to enter.

For example:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in());
for (i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    String x = scan.next();
    // Use 'x' assign it to a POJO or store it in an array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't process multi-line command line input.  There can only be one.

If you want multiple lines, you'll have to read them in using a Scanner and parsing each one.  You'll also need a condition to tell the program when you've entered the last line.  You should do this in a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like "\n" when you write on the command line. Then program Java to process that as a new line accordingly.

For example, if you wanted the following.

```
a b c
1
2
3
```

You could enter the following.

```
a b c\n 1\n 2\n 3
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your great reply but I need to enter them all at once without \n I think at the end I should go with scanner :)

Comment: @user2860721 Ok, that works. Don't forget to accept Tushar's answer then if that is the one that you decided to go with.